# Printer installer asks for root's password

Tags: printing

Something in my Kubuntu 14.04 system seems to be hosed.  When I look for printers in System Settings, I'm told that there aren't any, even though I had my printer installed and working not long ago.  If I try to install a new printer, I see a login screen with the user "root" (yes, literally the user "root"), and the root password doesn't work for this user.  How can I get past this (or, ideally, restore the previous printer installation)?

Comment: Did you set a root password?

Comment: I set a superuser password long ago and still have it.  There seems to be some confusion between the root user, i.e., the superuser, and the user named "root".  i can access the root account with "su" but I cannot log in as "root" (nor should I need to).

Comment: Unless you created another user named `root`, `root` and the superuser are the same. What does `getent passwd | grep root` say? If you can access the root account with just `su`, then the password for that should work for the `root` user (when prompted like in your question).

Comment: Here's what's in the passwd file: root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash.  The dialog box I see shows "root" as the user name and asks for a password.  But if I provide the password that works for su, it is rejected.  I've never seen a dialog box like that before that explicitly names "root" as the user.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was that my username wasn't listed for the group lpadmin.  Under those circumstances System Settings issues a very misleading prompt asking for "root"'s password.  Providing the root password doesn't satisfy the inquiry.